# DoS Attack my localhost tomcat

Tags: security, tomcat

I'm using tomcat 6 on localhost and running an application site.
I want to stress test using DoS from cmd prompt.
Can any one help me with this?

```
http://localhost:8080/web/login.xhtml
```

that's my url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stress test a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Tomcat, you are living in the Java world. The best Java-based tool I know of to perform load-testing is [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

It is honestly really great. You can set up complete workflows for a particular "user" to run-through, and then run lots of them in parallel. You can set up a bunch of different workflows to represent your various users and then launch an arbitrary number of them to run against your test site. You want 1 admin user and 5000 "regular" users? You got it. You want some users to be creating accounts and exploring the site while others continuously buy items in their shopping carts? No problem. Handles session-tracking, etc. You can even set the time interval between requests (or just go as fast as possible).

Unfortunately, JMeter is GUI-based, so not command-line. I'm not sure if you can use the GUI to create a testing profile and then launch it from the command-line.

If you want to stick with Apache, you can use ApacheBench (aka "ab") which comes with Apache httpd. It's pretty simple, and has some shortcomings due to its primitive threading-model: you can easily max-out ab's connection-making capabilities before you exhaust the server's resources.